# How to use Expandable in RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want use category and subCategory for items such as list UI and i get this data from server:

```
    Category1
      |
      |--SubCat1_1
         |
         |--subSubCat1_1
      |
      |--SubCat2
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_3
    Category2
      |
      |--SubCat2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat2_1
      |
      |--SubCat2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_3

and more ...
```

for this i want `RecyclerView`, but i don't know how

```
 |
 |--subSubCat2_2_1
 |
 |--subSubCat2_2_2
 |
 |--subSubCat2_2_3
```

subSubCat is very important for me, how can i show it?

Comment: Just use an ExpandableListView. It's not always recommended to use Recyclerview

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks my friend, but i should use recyclerview. can you help me?

Comment: According to who? What requirements do you have to use it

Comment: I'm only closing this as a duplicate because that other post addresses your initial question. Other than that, "I don't know how" isn't really a proper question for Stackoverflow. You should show some attempts at a solution or research first and show what you find